# How to testfor an item in a player's inventory that gets removed, and add it back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building my own custom created mini-game called murder.

I have 3 teams, and I only have to setup 1 more, but I've ran into a problem; When they get an arrow and shoot it a command block with `testfor` activates and starts giving them every single time when they have no arrows, an arrow.

The problem is I only want them to give them 1 arrow at a time, so when they shoot that arrow, they get 1 back within 30 ticks of time , but I don't have enough experience with command blocks to do so, anyone who can help me?

Comment: Don't assume the solution is to use `testfor` because it probably isn't.

Comment: then what could it be?

Comment: So you want the player to always have exactly one arrow in their inventory? Or that it stays at a certain amount (they have 3, shoot 1, get 1 back, still have 3)? Could an infinity bow accomplish what you are wanting?

Comment: No, just one. and after 3 seconds they shot it, they receive another one, but you must be in a certain team to receive it. so like this: 
`/testfor @a[team=Arrow] {Inventory{Slot9b,id:minecraft:air}`  and would activate if there is nothing in that specific slot, but my problem here is now that `minecraft:air` wont work, I need it to detect that slot 9 is empty.

Comment: @MinecraftDoge So if they have three arrows, and shoot one, what happens? Do they get another arrow, or does it only give them one if they have none left?

Comment: `or does it only give them one if they have none left?` < That one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer after testing, testing, and testing, and here's my solution:

You use scoreboard objectives, and use the testfor command, to look if you have the "use bow" stat. If you used it, the testfor command sends a signal to remove the arrow, and after a specified number of ticks, the arrow is returned.

I used replaceitem, but you *can* use `give`.

Answer (score -2):

```
/testfor @a[team=Arrow] {Inventory{Slot9b,id!:minecraft:arrow}
```

I beleve this does the trick, it tests for anything exept an arrow.

Comment: I did _!_ know ! works there. That's handy!

Comment: @TimPost This doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @colorfusion are you shure, I didn't test it but i found it on the web

Comment: @CoderGuy Where did you find it? The command definitely doesn't work, at least not in its current state.

Comment: @i found it in a large minigame project of a friend on the minecraft forums (post got deleted a while back)

Comment: Yes but there's 1 problem, how am I supposed to make it only give you 1 at a time? You need a bow to shoot the arrow m8.

Comment: how about you use infinity enchantment?